# why doesn't the rectangle move?

Tags: python, pygame

I don't get any errors but it doesn't work. I tried so many things but it never moves. I even copied ready scripts sometimes and they didn't move too. Please explain what am i doing wrong. Thanks from now.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

red = 100
green = 100
blue = 100
top = 265
left = 365
width = 70
height = 70

pygame.draw.rect(screen, [red, green, blue], [left, top, width, height])

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    left += 0.1
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the rectangle does move. However you must draw the rectangle in the application loop:

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    left += 0.1

    screen.fill(0) 
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [red, green, blue], [left, top, width, height])
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Comment: That was too helpful. Now i gained my motivation back. Thanks a lot sir!